# The thing that doesnt change in the algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, loop-invariant

```
k :=0
for i ←1 to n
     c←a[i]
           k←k+1
```

this is the algorithim to know the number of elements

Comment: I found that k<=i its true before the loop, during, and when it terminates @NickA

Comment: It's better to put all of the work that you have already done into the question, people will be more inclined to help you if they feel that you've at the very least tried to solve the problem. @Alexandra

Comment: Thank you, I will @NickA , if you can help please do

Comment: I suppose `b[i]` should be `b[j]`?

Comment: Yes I edited, thank you @VincentvanderWeele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, yes, `k <= i` is an invariant but not a very useful one. The reason we use invariants is that we can use them to prove the state after the loop. With your invariant you can prove that `k <= n` holds after the loop. Although very true, that doesn't really help you trying to prove what the loop really does.

So what kind of invariant would be useful? We want to prove that `k` is equal to the number of elements that are both in `a` and `b`. Since we are looping over the elements in `a`, a good choice would be: `k` equals the number of elements up to `a[i]` that are also in `b`.

---

We now need to prove that this invariant holds. I'll keep it a bit sketchy so it's still up to you to formalize this.

Initially, we need to show that `k = 0` is the number of elements before `a[1]` that are also in `b`. There are no such elements, so `k = 0` is correct.

Now, given that `ki` is the number of elements up to `a[i]` that are also in `b`, we need to prove that the invariant holds for `i+1`. There are two options: either `a[i+1]` is in `b`, or not.

- If `a[i+1]` in `b`, then the number of elements up to `a[i + 1]` that are in `b` is one greater than the number of elements up to `a[i]` that are in `b`. Using our invariant, we thus need to show that `ki+1 = ki + 1`.
- If `a[i+1]` not in `b`, then the number of elements up to `a[i + 1]` that are in `b` is equal to the number of elements up to `a[i]` that are in `b`. Using our invariant, we thus need to show that `ki+1 = ki`.

I'll leave it up to you to prove those.

Comment: I understand this, its true. So, now we want to prove the loop invariant through initialization, maintenance and termination. so in initialization we say that before the first iteration k=0. In maintanance what I should say or prove? @Vincent van der Weele

Comment: I added a part about a proof sketch. I hope you can take it from there.